# Why does this proof generalize for all norms? $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not an Euclidean Domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, euclidean-domain

Here's a proof from Dummit and Foote that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not an Euclidean Domain (based on the fact that it's not a PID).

[image]

I understand all of the proof except the last step. They carried out the proof for a specific choice of the field norm $N(a + b\sqrt{-5}) = a^2 + 5b^2$. How are they concluding that $R$ is not a Euclidean Domain **with respect to any norm**? They didn't even check for any norms apart from the specific $N$ they chose. Am I missing something?

Comment: AN euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez The word "Euclid" starts with a consonant sound: [/j/ (y in English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palatal_approximant). We use "a" in front of consonant sounds. E.g. on Wikipedia it says "In mathematics, more specifically in ring theory, a Euclidean domain (also called a Euclidean ring)."

Comment: @TrevorGunn didn't know that, thank you. In spanish, Euclid is pronounced with vowel sound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Euclidean domain is necessarily a principal ideal domain. Since this ring has a non-principal ideal, it cannot have a Euclidean norm.

You may be interested in reading about a PID which is not Euclidean. E.g. [http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~raw/MTH5100/PIDnotED.pdf](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Eraw/MTH5100/PIDnotED.pdf)

Comment: This does not answer my question. I know all EDs are PIDs. I'm asking why they chose a specific norm and claim to have generalized the result to all norms.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta They show it is not a PID using the given norm. Since it is not a PID it is not a Euclidean ddomain.